# How to add new column with values based on another column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I have the following df:

```
rs = np.random.RandomState(1979)
x = rs.randn(500)
g = np.tile(list("ABCDEFGHIJ"), 50)
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(x=x, g=g))
m = df.g.map(ord)
df["x"] += m

df

           x    g
0   64.038123   A
1   66.147050   B
2   66.370011   C
3   68.791019   D
4   70.583534   E
... ... ...
495 69.358022   F
496 72.212877   G
497 70.474247   H
498 73.251022   I
499 74.461828   J
```

I would Like to add a new column that consists of a number 1-10 that matches the letter of the alphabet, like so:

```
g new
A  1
B  2
C  3
D  4
```

The actual data I'm working with uses names instead of alphabet letters, but I obviously don't want to put those on here. But again, my goal is make a new column with a values I want for certain names.

Thanks!

Comment: Er.. `df["new col"] = range(1, len(df) + 1)` or `df.index`? I must be missing something. I think your spec is somewhat oversimplified. What logic governs the values you want for certain names?

Comment: I'm making a joyplot using joypy but the ordering is random. There is a an "order" parameter that needs a numerical value. I want to order the names of people in my dataframe in the order I want them to appear on the joyplot

Comment: No, I just simply want to order them in the way I think the graph looks best.

Comment: I have about 400 rows of 5 individuals. I could create a list [1,2,3,4,5], but I am just curious how to map each number to the individual I want

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214947/discussion-between-bismo-and-ggorlen).

Comment: Actually you could use `ord`: `df['new'] = [ord(i)-64 for i in df["g"]]`. You don't have to create a `dict` to map just for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a dictionary that maps names to their respective ordered position you want in your graph is the way to go. Here's a simple example:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({"Name": ["Alice", "Bob", "Bob", "Alice", "Charlie"]})
>>> ordering = {"Alice": 1, "Bob": 3, "Charlie": 2}
>>> df["Ordering"] = df["Name"].map(ordering)
>>> df
      Name  Ordering
0    Alice         1
1      Bob         3
2      Bob         3
3    Alice         1
4  Charlie         2
```